# Send trap with Perl (net-snmp)

Tags: perl, snmp, net-snmp, snmp-trap

I run snmptrapd and can see incoming trap, when send trap via snmptrap

```
snmptrap -c public -v 2c localhost "" 1.3.3.3.3.3.3.3 1.2.2.2.2.2.2 s "Aliens here"
```

But I no have trap, when send via Perl script

```
use SNMP;

$sess = new SNMP::Session(DestHost => '127.0.0.1', RemotePort => "162" );

$sess->trap(enterprise=>'.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021', # or 'ucdavis' [default]
                agent => '127.0.0.1', # or 'localhost',[dflt 1st intf on host]
                generic => specific,  # can be omitted if 'specific' supplied
                specific => 5,        # can be omitted if 'generic' supplied
                uptime => 1234,       # dflt to localhost uptime (0 on win32)
                [[ifIndex, 1, 1],[sysLocation, 0, "here"]]);
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SNMP trapping, but your `snmptrap` doesn't look the same as your perl equivalent - where's the `RemotePort`, and how does `.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021` relate to `1.3.3.3.3.3.3.3 1.2.2.2.2.2.2`?

Comment: In first one snmptrap's default target port is 162 so don't think that the issue, and questioner says first one ok. Also the different OIDs .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021 vs 1.3.3.3.3.3.3.3 1.2.2.2.2.2.2, shouldn't (!) matter and there looks to be a more fundamental comms problem.

Comment: Using a tool like Wireshark or `tcpdump`, check the traffic of the outgoing interface to see if the packet is really sent. If it is, check whether it arrives on the receiving side.

Answer (score 1):

Your second version i.e. the perl one is not specifying community or version, unlike the first one. Try adding them

```
$sess = new SNMP::Session(DestHost => '127.0.0.1', 
                                      RemotePort => "162",
                                      Community => "public,
                                      Version => 2);
```

Also see http://www.remothelast.altervista.org/SNMP_Perl.html
and  http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/perl-SNMP-README.html for SNMP::Session usage.